# Any possibility to automate the whole Azure pipelines creation using Azure Devops REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-deployment, azure-devops-extensions

I was looking for a solution of creating automation process for creation of pipelines to eliminate all the manual process we do while creating a pipeline in Azure devops portal.

Example:
If i want to deploy my Python based application and it doesn't have any pipelines defined previously. I want to create a pipeline and deploy the app to the Azure server whole process should be done with out manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to create somehow your YAML file or use what you have already. Of course you can prepare some templates and reuse them and if you define folder structure for your project and you will keep it then you will minimize yoour manual tasks. Once you have your YAML file defines you can use for instance az cli command:

```bsh
az pipelines create --name 'Your pipeline name' --description 'Your pipeline description' --repository https://github.com/your-repo --branch master --yml-path your-file-in-repo.yaml --org https://dev.azure.com/your-organizaton --project 'your project'
```

From what I see this is not possible to use REST API to define YAML pipelines. Please take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/issues/251).

So if you use calssic build it will be possible to use REST API. You can take a look [here](https://newsignature.com/articles/automating-build-pipeline-creation-using-azure-devops-services-rest-api/).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?definitionToCloneId={definitionToCloneId}&definitionToCloneRevision={definitionToCloneRevision}&api-version=5.1
```

You can for instance indicate here which definition should be cloned as a base for your new build.